Using /start, the “inline” button should appear in the telegram bot, and when pressed again, it should disappear and appear again
Using /start, the “inline” button should appear in the telegram bot, and when pressed again, it should disappear and appear again.
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

def go(message):

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    switch50 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='GO', callback_data='btn10')
    markup.add(switch50)
    bot.edit_message_reply_markup()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Заходи!",reply_markup=markup)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean by "disappear and appear again"? Do you want that button to be replaced with another one?

So that it is replaced with the same button, so that there are no copies when you repeat /start
